# C# intentionally flickering

Tags: c#, graphics

i'm currently working on a project which must provide intentionally flickering of some part of UI (white rectangle which must change color to black).

That changing of color must be done at some frequency, let's say 60Hz, which is practically supported on every monitor.

Flickering must follow the input data stream (binary coded, 0 or 1).

Which is the most elegant way to do this in C# (some code example would be useful) ?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744366/double-buffering-with-vsync-in-sync-with-refresh-rate-of-screen-c-sharp-wind

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, unless you use DirectX or OpenGL. None of existing UI frameworks is designed to support this use case. Games, on the other hand are build on the requirement that screen needs to change quickly and so their frameworks are build around that.

My recommendation is to create a DirectX context and drawing area in place of that control and then render it using DirectX. If you are drawing just plain rectangle, then it shouldn't be problem to reach 1000Hz (eg. 1000FPS)